# How can I add an array to a struct property in C?

Tags: c

How can I add an array to a struct property in C? Here you have an example of what I want to accomplish:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char age;
    short number;
    int grades[10];
    char name[80];
    char address[120];
} Student;

Student s;

s.age = 23;
s.number = 10;
strcpy(s.name, "Jon");
strcpy(s.address, "Doe");

int oldGrades[10] = {1, 8, 2, 2, 4, 9, 9, 8, 4, 1};

s.grades = oldGrades; // Error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

How can I add the array **oldGrades** to the property **grades** of my recently created object?

Comment: This has nothing to do with structs.

Comment: `s.grades = oldGrades;` --> `memcpy(s.grades, oldGrades, sizeof(oldGrades));`

Comment: If number is a phone number and not an id then it should be a string.

Comment: As an addendum to the other comments, you could also wrap the grades array in its own struct. You can copy the contents of a struct from one to another with assignment. Not suggesting it is good design practice, but just another technically correct way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually copy the array contents using for loop.

```
for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
s.grades[i] = oldGrades[i];
```

Or you can use memcpy.

```
memcpy(s.grades, oldGrades, sizeof(oldGrades))
```

`c` doesn't provide facility `s.grades = oldGrades` to copy array by assignment.

Comment: Introducing `memcpy()` way in this situation is a good solution but i think `for()`is better to a newbie.